# NT Kernel using a full core in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, kernel

I have three identical Windows 7 machines, and the OS is up to date. I just figured out that all three have always a minimum 13% CPU load (1/8 cores) which is due to NT kernel according to the task manager (and not due to a service).

By searching the web I found out that a driver is maybe in cause. I have downloaded the performance monitoring tools from Windows 7 SDK, as well as the UIforETG frontend. I have successfully recorded a trace and visualized it in the SDK GUI.
There I can find the "system" process which roughly has 13% of the hits, but I cannot find any information about the drivers.

How can I identify the driver kernel use?

Comment: For Windows 7, use the [Win10v1511 SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771)/WPT, newer version no longer work in Windows 7

Comment: were you able to use WPR/WPA to trace the issue?